# Joint probability of two paired conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

Suppose that the probabilities of the positive outcomes of `B` and `C` condition on the positive outcome of event A are:

$p_1 = Pr(B+|A+) = 0.8 $

$p_2 = Pr(C+|A+) = 0.9 $

And we also know that the correlation coefficient between $p_1$ and $p_2$ is `0.75` (i.e. B and C are paired binary outcomes, e.g. a same cohort of patients tested for COVID-19 at day0 and day3). My question is what the joint probability of $Pr(C+,B+|A+)$ is in a closed form and the value in this case.

Comment: That's insufficient information unless $\Pr(A+)=1.$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let assume $Pr(A+) = 0.3$.

Comment: That doesn't help. **You need information equivalent to the _conditional_ correlation** to obtain a unique answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B|A\sim Bernoulli(p_B)$ and $C|A\sim Bernoulli(p_C)$, and let
$$
Cor(B,C|A) = \rho.
$$
We know that
$$
\begin{aligned}
Cor(B,C|A) &= \frac{Cov(B,C|A)}{\sqrt{Var(B|A)Var(C|A)}}\\
&=\frac{E[BC|A]-E[B|A]E[C|A]}{\sqrt{Var(B|A)Var(C|A)}}\\
&=\frac{E[BC|A]-p_Bp_C}{\sqrt{p_B(1-p_B)p_C(1-p_C)}}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $E[BC|A] = P(B = 1, C = 1|A)$, for in any other case, the product $BC$ is equal to zero. This is, if $C = 0$ or $B = 0$ then $BC = 0$. Only when both are one we have that $BC = 1$. Thus, using the above and solving for $E[BC|A]$ we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(B = 1, C = 1|A) &= E[BC|A]\\
&= \rho \sqrt{p_B(1-p_B)p_C(1-p_C)} + p_Bp_C.
\end{aligned}
$$
Given the data, $\rho = 0.75$, $p_B = 0.8$ and $p_C = 0.9$. Thus,
$$
P(B,C|A) = 0.75\sqrt{0.8\times 0.2 \times 0.9\times 0.1} + 0.8\times 0.9 = 0.81.
$$

Comment: The question states the correlation coefficient is known, not the conditional correlation.

Comment: It states that the correlation between $p_1$ and $p_2$, the conditional probabilities, is 0.75, so I assumed the author refers to the conditional correlation. But indeed, if it is not, then we do not have enough information.

Comment: Thanks @JesúsA.! Your assumption was correct!